# Мне нужно чтобы мой запрос возвращал названия по дате. Тоесть чтобы по дате сортировал названия

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть запрос. В нем я хочу вывести по дате отсортировать все что я додал в БД и вывести

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Show>> GetShowsSortedByDateForAllTheatres()
        {
            var query = from show in dataBaseContext.Shows
                        select new Show { Id = show.Id, Name = show.Name, TheatreId = show.TheatreId, Date = show.Date, Theatre = show.Theatre };
            query.OrderBy(date => date.Date);
            return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Но оно зараз мне выводит просто значения по порядку как я додал в БД их.
Не ужели так нельзя делать?

```
query.OrderBy(date => date.Date);
```

А как правильно?

Comment: А что такое у вас Date поле?Дата создания?

Comment: @RomanIeromenko нет это параметр  в БД Дата когда произойдет шоу

Comment: Метод OrderBy не меняет исходную последовательность, а возвращает отсортированную: `query = query.OrderBy(date => date.Date);`. К тому же orderby можно писать в сам запрос без использования отдельного метода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно, LINQ методы не изменяют исходную коллекцию, а возвращают новую => `query.OrderBy(date => date.Date);` тут вы получается новую отсортированную коллекцию, которыю никуда не сохраняете.

Comment: Я ничего не понял, ей надо в query все вывести не меняя в БД

Comment: @RomanIeromenko  iluxa правильный ответ дал. Помогло